# How to refresh the frame of buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Below is the code where the button on right click delete functionality performed.
Button is actually deleted from the json file where I am storing for refresh. But when I recall ButtonCreate the frame is not showing with refreshed button.

What could have went wrong over here?

```
class ButtonCreate(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(master=parent)
        self.frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), weight=1, uniform='b')
        self.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5), weight=1, uniform='b')
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.tkraise()
        self.create_widgets()
    
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.retrive_button_info()
        row_item = 0
        col = 0
        self.vars=[]
        self.button_names =[]
        self.labels =[]
        for i in range(len(list(self.RECREATED_BUTTON_TEXT))):
            if row_item > 13 or col > 5:
                row_item += 1
                col = 0
            if i <= 80:
                self.button_num = i
                self.var_name = f"var{i}"
                self.vars.append(ctk.StringVar(value=self.var_name))
                self.b_name = ctk.CTkButton(
                    self, 
                    text=self.RECREATED_BUTTON_TEXT[i][0], 
                    command=lambda i=i: self.button_click(i),
                    textvariable=i,)
                self.b_name.grid(row=row_item, column=col, sticky='w', padx=5, pady=5)
                self.b_name.bind("<Button-3>", self.show_menu)
                print(self.b_name)
                self.button_names.append(self.b_name)
                self.labels.append(self.b_name._text)
                col += 1
        self.configure(fg_color=BG_COLOR)
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=5, pady=5)
        self.RECREATED_BUTTON_TEXT =[]
        
    def show_menu(self, event):
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.master, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Edit", command=self.EditButton)
        self.menu.add_command(label="Delete", command=lambda:self.DeleteButton(event))
        try:
            self.menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root,0)
        finally:
            self.menu.grab_release()
    

    def EditButton(self):
        self.retrive_button_info()
        print(self.RECREATED_BUTTON_TEXT[self.button_num-1])
        
    def DeleteButton(self, event):
        file_name = 'C:\\users\\' + getpass.getuser() + '\\button_info.json'
        self.retrive_button_info()
        widget = event.widget
        children = self.winfo_children()
        # row = widget.grid_info()['row']
        # col = widget.grid_info()['column']
        WRITE_BUTTON_LIST = [x for x in self.RECREATED_BUTTON_TEXT if x[0] != widget.cget('text')]
        if event.widget in children:
            index = children.index(event.widget)
            children.remove(event.widget)
            self.labels.pop(index)
            widget.destroy()
        with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(WRITE_BUTTON_LIST, f)
        # self.show_bdelete_confirmation()
        ButtonCreate(self)
```

If I do the self.grid_forget() I cannot see any buttons.